# Thinkpad 13 2G - i7-7500U - freeze after wakeup

Tags: suspend, freeze, thinkpad, hibernate

I found my Thinkpad 13 2G - i7-7500U works out of the box with Ubuntu 17.4 except for sleep: it just freeze right after wake up complete.

Can anybody reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you post your Graphics Card info with `lspci | grep VGA -A` ? This situation is mostly related with X.org driver. Usually people got solved this using the property Nvidia driver.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)

Answer (score 0):

I found problem is caused by the touch screen driver. During wakeup the module i2c_hid drop out a lot of error visible in the kernel log as:

```
Apr 20 20:25:46 domenico-T132G kernel: [  230.882336] i2c_hid i2c-RAYD0001:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (58/16946)
```

this problem set the kernel in some strange condition casing it to OOPS.

The workaround is to unload the module before go to sleep and re-load after wake-up.

I created a script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/disabletouch that do this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        pre)
                modprobe -r i2c_hid
                sleep 1
                ;;
        post)
                sleep 1
                modprobe i2c_hid
                ;;
    esac
fi
```

I would appreciate if someone can send the problem to the Kernel guys.